# Header component keeps rerendering when changing Route on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

When pressing {Link} and changing Route, the header component NavBar keeps rerendering, even when is outside the Switch component from react-router-dom.

here are the files:

Main index.js file:

```js
import React from 'react'
import styles from './styles.css'
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './Home'
import Settings from './Settings'
import Layout from './Layout'
import Contact from './Contact'
import NavBar from 'App/components/NavBar'

export default class MainHome extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/settings" component={Settings} />
          <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Home.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import styles from './styles.css'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
        <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Contact.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import styles from './styles.css'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

export default class Contact extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.container}>
        Contact
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The current project is pretty simple: the index.js file has inside the Home and Contact components, and the NavBar component as a header outside the Switch.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious. What version of react-router-dom are you using, and what does the component with your `Router` in it look like (Add the markup to the question)? I tested it here and everything seems to work https://codesandbox.io/s/jpnov36x95

Comment: One possible solution would be to add a `key` attribute to the `NavBar` to tell react it's not changing. Example: `<NavBar key="navbar" />`

Answer (score 0):

@MattyJ I'm using react-router-dom@^4.2.1. The component with the Router looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react'
import Root from 'App/Root'
import Pages from './Pages'
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter key={Math.random()}>
        <Root>
          <Pages />
        </Root>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

Pages encapsulates two components: App, where is located the Switch component from my question, and Auth for managing autentication:

```js
import React from 'react'
import authRouteRegex from './Auth/routeRegex'
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import DynamicComponent from 'App/components/DynamicComponent'
import App from './App'

@withRouter
export default class Pages extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    location: PropTypes.object
  }

  render() {
    if (authRouteRegex.test(this.props.location.pathname)) {
      const Component = DynamicComponent(() => import('./Auth'))
      return <Component />
    }
    return <App />
  }
}
```